# How come Captain America is still alive?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* Captain America is fighting Thanos, he's almost dead, his suit is tattered, his shield is almost broken, and at the end he's still alive! Iron Man only wields the Stones but

> he's dead. And Captain America is still alive?!

Why is this?

Comment: Firstly, Cap fought Thanos whilst wielding Mjolnir. Secondly, he has has the super-soldier serum in his blood. Thirdly, The stones are to much to bear for a mortal; even Thanos suffered heavily. The comparison between using the stones and fighting Thanos cannot be used because they are totally different.

Comment: “Iron Man only wields the Stones” — only. Right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He's Captain America after all.

Remember, last time Captain America was trained as a soldier, and the fact  he's a **super soldier** makes it more possible that he can still be alive. Yes, though Thanos is probably more powerful than him, it looks he doesn't do much damage to kill him.

Answer (score 11):

A few of things really:

#### Captain America was injected with the Super Soldier serum

In *Captain America: The First Avenger* we see Steve's origin story and how he became Captain America. In it we see Steve is injected with the Super Soldier serum which enhances the man and his morals. It also makes him taller, stronger, more muscle, better reflexes etc. Steve isn't your ordinary man. He's also long lived with really good regeneration.

> **Steve Rogers:** Dr. Erskine said that… the serum wouldn’t just effect my muscles, it would effect my cells. Create a protective system of regeneration and healing. Which means um…I can’t get drunk. Did you know that?
>
> <sub>*Captain America: The First Avenger*</sub>

#### Thanos doesn't actually do that much damage

If you watch the fight scene a bit more closely you'll notice that Thanos doesn't actually do too much damage to Cap. Most of the damage in the scene when he has Mjolnir is actually inflicted upon the shield and he only really winds Cap a few times. He doesn't really inflict much upon him.

#### Cap is also wielding Mjolnir

In this particular fight with Thanos Cap is wielding Mjolnir which means, per the enchantment placed upon it by Odin, that he gains the power of Thor. This means "Thunder God" but also his strength, regeneration amongst other things.

> **Odin:** Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

---

It's also worth noting that your comparison to Tony is faulty. The Infinity Stones are the most powerful objects in the universe. Even the act of touching the Power Stone directly is enough to kill someone as we see in *Guardians of the Galaxy*. Tony wielded all 6 *and* snapped with them which caused his death. Even Thanos was very badly hurt both times he used them. There's just no comparison really between the Stones and fighting Thanos; Thanos may be powerful but he's nothing in comparison to the Stones.

Comment: *Whosoever wields this hammer shall possess the power of Thor*. Captain America possessed the power of Thor, so maybe his strength as well? idk.

Comment: How do I mark both as good? Both are very good answers and detailed...

Comment: @SpaceGeorgie You can upvote both (click the up arrow) but can only accept one as the most helpful.

Comment: But it says I need 15 rep to vote!

Comment: @SpaceGeorgie True forgot about that, in that case you will have to wait until you have 15 to upvote the answers but can accept the most helpful one now.

Comment: @Shreedhar Aye meant to add that in, done now.